# Where to define Async class in a multi tab android project

Tags: java, android, json, api, asynchronous

I am working on an android project with three tabs (3 tabs are created using Fragment class). 
I created one Async inner class in Mainactivity and calling that class from onCreate(), but nothing is happening in the Logcat. Can anyone suggest me Where to define Async class which is getting resource in JSON format. Any better way of doing this thing is also welcome.

---

```
package com.utb.iftekhar.cityweatherappsnapshot1;

public class Tab2Fragment extends Fragment {

    private static final String TAG="Tab2Fragment";


    private Button button;
    private static  final String CITY_NAME_SEARCHED="cityNameSearched";

    private List<String> historyList;
    private ListView historyListView;
    private ArrayAdapter<String> arrayAdapter;

    String cityNameSearched="";

    @Nullable
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View view=inflater.inflate(R.layout.tab2_frag, container, false);
        historyListView=view.findViewById(R.id.historyList);
        historyList=new ArrayList<>();

        if(getArguments()!=null){
            cityNameSearched=getArguments().getString(CITY_NAME_SEARCHED);//Not able to set values to the ctiNameSearched variable.
        }else
        {
            Log.i("No","Arguments");//
        }

       if(!(cityNameSearched==null)  ||  !cityNameSearched.equals("")){
           historyList.add(cityNameSearched);
           Log.i("before", cityNameSearched);
           Log.i("Value in tab2frag",cityNameSearched);
       }


        return view;
 }

//This method is returning the searched city name searched int the edit text from fragment(Tab1Fragment) but not able to access this value in cityNameSearched variable.
    public void updateEditText(String newText){
        Log.i("received from 1 in 2",newText);
        this.cityNameSearched=newText;
    }

/*
    @Override
    public void onAttach(Context context) {
        super.onAttach(context);
        if(context instanceof Tab2FragmentListener){
            tab2FragmentListener=(Tab2FragmentListener)context;
        }else{
            throw new RuntimeException(context.toString()+
                    " must implement Tab2FragmentListener"
            );
        }
    }


    @Override
    public void onDetach() {
        super.onDetach();
        tab2FragmentListener=null;
    }*/



}
```

---

```
public class Tab1Fragment extends Fragment{
    private String weatherResults;
    private Tab1FragmentListener tab1FragmentListener;
    private String cityNameSearched;

    public interface Tab1FragmentListener{
        void onInput1Set(String input);
    }
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, 
       @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
       View view=inflater.inflate(R.layout.tab1_frag, container, false);
        getWeatherButton=(Button)view.findViewById(R.id.getWeatherButton);
        searchCityByName=(EditText)view.findViewById(R.id.searchCityByName);
        weatherResultTextView=(TextView)view.findViewById(R.id.weatherResult);
        mainActivity=new MainActivity();



        getWeatherButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {    
                downloadTask=new DownloadTask(new DownloadTask.AsyncResponse() {

                    @Override
                    public void processFinish(String output) {

                        if(!output.equals("")){

                            weatherResultTextView.setText(output);
                        }else{
                            weatherResultTextView.setText("");
                        }
                    }
                });
                  cityNameSearched=searchCityByName.getText().toString().trim();
                    tab1FragmentListener.onInput1Set(cityNameSearched);
                Log.i("CityNameSearched", cityNameSearched);
                try {
                    String encodedCityName= URLEncoder.encode(cityNameSearched,"UTF-8" );
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }

                downloadTask.execute("https://openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?q="+cityNameSearched+"&appid=b6907d289e10d714a6e88b30761fae22");

                Log.i("Button Cliked","Clicked");
                InputMethodManager mgr=(InputMethodManager) getActivity().getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
                mgr.hideSoftInputFromWindow(searchCityByName.getWindowToken(), 0);

            }
        });
        return view;
    }

    @Override
    public void onAttach(Context context) {
        super.onAttach(context);
        if(context instanceof Tab1FragmentListener){
            tab1FragmentListener=(Tab1FragmentListener)context;
        }else{
            throw new RuntimeException(context.toString()+
            " must implement Tab1FragmentListener"
            );
        }
    }


    @Override
    public void onDetach() {
        super.onDetach();
        tab1FragmentListener=null;
    }

    public void updateEditText(String newText){
        searchCityByName.setText(newText);
    }

}
```

---

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements Tab1Fragment.Tab1FragmentListener {
    private static final String TAG="MainActivity";
    private SectionsPageAdapter mySectionPageAdapter;
    private ViewPager viewPager;
    private DataForTabs dataForTabs;
    private Tab1Fragment tab1Fragment;
    private Tab2Fragment tab2Fragment;
    String input="";
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        Log.d(TAG,"onCreate: Starting.");
        tab1Fragment=new Tab1Fragment();

        Log.i(" From 1 to main ", input);//No Log appears for this input variable

        mySectionPageAdapter=new SectionsPageAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager());
        //set up the ViewPager with the sections adaptor
        viewPager=(ViewPager)findViewById(R.id.container);
        setupViewPager(viewPager);

        TabLayout tabLayout=(TabLayout)findViewById(R.id.tabs);
        tabLayout.setupWithViewPager(viewPager);
    }

    public void setupViewPager(ViewPager viewPager){
        SectionsPageAdapter adapter=new 
       SectionsPageAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager());
        adapter.addFragment(new Tab1Fragment(),"Home");
        adapter.addFragment(new Tab2Fragment(),"History");
        adapter.addFragment(new Tab3Fragment(),"About");
        viewPager.setAdapter(adapter);
    }

    @Override
    public void onInput1Set(String input) {

          tab2Fragment.updateEditText(input);
           this.input=input;
    }
}
```

Comment: Could you please provide some code snippets to yout SO question?

Comment: am coding for a weather app with three tabbed screens, which takes the city name in the edit text and displays the weather details on the same tab. I want to store the searched city name in another tab as history using ListView(Persistent using SharedPreferences). Help me with how to move forward. 1. Where to write the code for shared preferences. and how to make it dynamic so that history can be updated dynamically.

Comment: I have added the code snippet for my question below